# Taking the minute from the JSON time index pulled, to compare with current time.

Tags: python, json, pandas, indexing, time-series

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from time import strftime


df = pd.read_json('https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=EURUSD,USDJPY,AUDUSD,&api_key=KEY')
df = df.pivot_table('price', 'timestamp', 'symbol')

min = int(time.strftime("%M"))
minpull= df.index[0]

print(min)
print(minpull) 

    while min <= minpull:
    print(df)
```

How to i get the minute as a singular number to compare to current actual time?

The code is pulling data from the URL as JSON format and put in to a pandas dataframe. I want to compare the time that was pulled which was set at the index(pullmin), with the current time(min). That way, when the next minute comes, the code will then pull the next set data and i will have minute by minute data. Eventually, it will be added the same pandas df but i also havent figured that out either.

Comment: Please show us how your dataframe looks like.

Comment: When i put:  while min <= minpull:
  print(df). I get this output:  1
2018-11-05 21:01:16. The first one is the minute from the (min) and the rest is from the (minpull). Then this error, 
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Get one dataframe, wait 60 seconds append the next one:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from time import strftime, sleep

def get_data(): 
    df = pd.read_json('https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=EURUSD,USDJPY,AUDUSD,&api_key=KEY')
    return df.pivot_table('price', 'timestamp', 'symbol')

df = get_data()
for k in range(5): # takes 5 minutes ...
    sleep(60)
    df2 = get_data()
    df.append(df2)
```

Untested, got no key.

Comment: This didnt work. Im doing it like this so that im pulling the data from the url exacty on the minute and not every minute. Ive used the schedule module too but its not exactly every 60 seconds for some reason

Comment: You wont get exactly on the minute . you'll drift by some amount anyhow. If you want to get time critical data this wont work I agree - but using this kind of data for trading when other ppl rent space in the same rack in the same datacenter so latency is minimal to shoot best prices automatically -- you will loose using python in that game. Read f.e. https://cryptodisrupt.com/what-is-latency-and-why-is-it-so-important/